# Which privilege needs a mysql-user to grant the EXECUTE-privilege to an other user?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I have a user, called "user_creator", in my MySQL 5.5.60 server. This user was created to add new user and databases and grant privileges to this new created users (so and "admin", but with fewer rights).

Following privileges for this "user_creator" are granted:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, CREATE USER, EXECUTE, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'user_creator'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION
```

This configuration works well. If the "user_creator" creates a new user with...

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON foo.* TO 'foo_01'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'foo';
```

... it works.

But, if the "user_creator" want to grant the EXECUTE privilege to the new user, like

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON foo.* TO 'foo_01'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'foo';
```

an error occurred:

> ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user
>   ‘user_creator'@'x.x.x.x’ to database ‘foo’;

Has anyone an idea which privilege the "user_creator" needs to grant the EXECUTE-privilege to a new created user? I don't want to user the root- or an root-like-user to do this action.